# Disable angular button using ng-disable using $scope var in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two buttons in my view and I want to disable the Summary button until my view is loaded.

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-init="showData = 1">
    <button ng-model="showData" type="button" ng-class='{"btn btn-primary": showData == 1, "btn btn-white": showData != 1}' ng-click="showData = 1">Headline</button>
    <button ng-model="showData" type="button" ng-class='{"btn btn-primary":showData == 2, "btn btn-white": showData != 2}'  ng-click="showData = 2; summaryCall()">Summary</button>
</div>
```

I have a variable **$scope.loadMainView = false**, this change to **true** when the response of a Web service is ok, so I want want to disable my button until that variable change to true, but I dont know how to 
achive that. I was thinking on ng-init for a $scope variable to be initialized as false and then asing that to an ng-disable or something like that but I'm not sure, Im new in angular and maybe my 
approach is not at all correct.

Some help will be great.

Comment: Setting its initial value to `false` and changing it when receiving response from your service is a good way of handling this.

Comment: But in the view I dont know what to put, ng-init or what?
I was thinking on create a $scope variable and set the default value to false until the services response is ok, my problem is on the view that I dont know how to manage that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-disabled`

```
<button ng-disabled="!loadMainView" type="button"></button>
```

> This directive sets the disabled attribute on the element if the expression inside ngDisabled evaluates to truthy.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your time, one more question, what if I want to evaluate to variales, like this?

ng-disabled="!loadMainView || !loadSecondaryView

Is that correct?

Comment: `ng-disabled` simply evaluates the subsequent expression. In this case it would mean only one of those two would have to be correct

Answer (score 2):

using the *ngDisabled* directive is the right way to go

```
<button ng-disabled="!loadMainView" type="button"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :)